# Embed a Python script in .blend?

Tags: python

I have a `.blend` file and an accompanying python script that needs running very often when the `.blend` file is open.

As such, I wish to just "embed" the script into the text editor window. This way, I only need to save one `.blend` file instead of a `.blend` and a `.py`. The ideal startup window of the `.blend` file looks like this.

[image]

Can this be specified when I create this `.blend` file with Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the text datablock `something.py` and tick the 'register' checkbox. It'll run whenever you load the file, just like you want.

You do need to enable autorunning Python scripts in your user preferences (this is disabled by default for security reasons).

Answer (score 1):

If you leave the script in that window and save the blend file it should be saved along with UI layout, on default saving settings at least.

Comment: I am creating this file in Python, not with GUI

Comment: You took a picture of it. The file is loaded in Blender. It is in the GUI.

Comment: "The ideal startup window of the .blend file [created with Python] looks like this."